How to get the list item value in word template
I am using Aspose reporting engine to generate report with word template,
I pass a json data into JsonDataSource,and I want to check the item value in word template,
but data is converted to a DataRow and i can not find the value
here is the way i access the data value in word template:
<<[m.testCategory.Any(x => x[2].ToString()== "1")]>>

it is very strange that i can access the data by index 2 in my local environment, but not work in server environment.
what is the way to access the data in word template,
Thank you in advance for your time and assistance.
here is the code:
var manager = new Manager
{
    testCategory = new int[] { 1 ,2,3}
};

string managerJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(manager);
byte[] managerJsonBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(managerJson);
using MemoryStream managerJsonStream = new MemoryStream(managerJsonBytes);
var managerJsonJsondata = new JsonDataSource(managerJsonStream, new JsonDataLoadOptions
{
    SimpleValueParseMode = JsonSimpleValueParseMode.Strict,
});
var dataSources = new Object[] { managerJsonJsondata };

ReportingEngine engine = new ReportingEngine();
engine.Options = ReportBuildOptions.RemoveEmptyParagraphs;
engine.BuildReport(doc, dataSources, new string[] { "m" });
doc.Save("C:\\WorkSpace\\" + "ReportingEngine.HelloWorld.docx");

public class Manager
{
    public int[] testCategory { get; set; }
}


Please fix your question, so we can actually recreate your problem: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

According to the documentation you could create a variable once and use it across the document. Is there any reason for you to get the data by index?

Because I couldn't find a better way to obtain the data, what I want is to check whether a specified value exists in an array. For example, if I pass a JSON data {"testCategory": [1, 2, 3]}, I want to check if the data contains the value 1 in word template. If the data contains 1, I want to mark the checkbox as checked.

@xinyuxi there are limitations working with this library. You could put the logics in c# code before generating the report rather than in the report template. Getting access to basic bool flags in manager object works fine from template.

According to https://docs.aspose.com/words/net/accessing-json-data/, here is how an item of a simple-value JSON array can be accessed:

Note – To reference a JSON object property that is an array of simple-type values, the name of the property (for example, “Child”) should be used in a template document, whereas the same name with the “_Text” suffix (for example, “Child_Text”) should be used to reference the value of an item of this array.

So, <<[m.testCategory.Any(x => x[2].ToString()== "1")]>> can be replaced with <<[m.testCategory.Any(x => x.testCategory_Text.ToString()== "1")]>>.
As a note, using of ToString() is not necessary, since comparison of numeric values is supported.
